# How can I sort hasMany associations in scaffolded GSPs in Grails 3.1.8

Tags: grails, gsp

I have a domain object, `Question`, with a hasMany relationship to another domain class, `Option`, which implements `Comparable<Option>`.  I would like the options to be sorted in the GSP.  Is there an easy way to do this, or do I need to generate the views and edit them manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be relatively easy, however finding the answer was a real pain because the documentation for the Grails Field Plugin is lacking detail.

Just add a GSP called `grails-app/views/[domain-class]/[action]/[property]/_displayWidget.gsp`.

The contents of that file is a template that handles the sorting and displaying...

**grails-app/views/question/show/options/_displayWidget.gsp**

```
<ul>
    <g:each in="${value?.sort()}" var="val">
        <li><g:link controller="${val.class}" action="show" id="${val.id}">${val}</g:link></li>
    </g:each>
</ul>
```